# Python lists, strings, conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, file

Hello I am looking to get a string that looks like this :
`string: "[[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]]"`
To an actual list:
`list: [[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]`

My code reads from an file which stores a flat out str(list) and I want to retrieve it from the file as a list not a str. If you have a better way of storing and retrieving it would help a lot.

Comment: "My code reads from an file which stores a flat out str(list)" **don't do that**. Don't just dump the `str` representation of an object into a file ... use an *actual serialization format*, like `JSON` or `pickle` or heck, in this case, even csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use json library

```py
import json
l = json.loads("[[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]]")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "[[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]]"
print(string)
print(type(string))

new = eval(string)
print(new)
print(type(new))
```

Output:

```
[[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]]
<class 'str'>
[[[[1.0], 1.0], [[1.0], 1.0]], [[[1.0, 1.0], 1.0], [[1.0, 1.0], 1.0]]]
<class 'list'>
```

Not sure if safe, but I used eval(string), which converted it to the list

Comment: Always watch out for using eval() outside of specific use cases. It is not safe.

Comment: This is **not** a good answer. Please check the duplicate

Comment: @flamusdiu in this case it isn't a problem, but the OP shouldn't be storing the string representation to a text file as a form of serialization to begin with

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agreed but just pointing out that watch out for using eval(). It's not a silver bullet.